# Send function key stroke from AutoHotkey to OBS Studio

Tags: autohotkey, obs, obs-studio

I am trying to send a keystroke to OBS Studio using AutoHotkey.

The code I am using is

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On
hWnd := WinExist("ahk_exe obs64.exe")
ControlSend,, {F5}, ahk_id %hWnd%
```

The function I want to trigger is "start recording"

[image: setting in OBS]

Nothing is delivered. There is a rumour that the latest OBS does not allow for ControlSend. Is that true? How do I circumvent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SetKeyDelay`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) (or separate up & down events with delay in between) to make the key be held down for a bit longer.

```
;hold down for 50ms
SetKeyDelay, -1, 50
ControlSend, , {F5}, ahk_exe obs64.exe
```

Also, assuming you don't need the hwnd for something else, there's no need to get it.
And it should work just fine as well without detecting hidden windows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but that is not working (OBS does not react). I am using OBS 24.0.3 and autohotkey 1.1.33.01.

Comment: Hmm, it's working perfectly fine for me. I'm on the latest OBS version though. But I doubt that would make a difference. And you're sure you didn't maybe have something else in your script that could've messed with the test? Try running a new script with nothing else but just those 2 lines of code I posted above.

Comment: Yeah, it worked! Must see how other parts of the script messed it up.

Comment: `DetectHiddenWindows, On` before those two lines makes them not work.

Comment: Also, WinExist does not need that line, it finds the hWnd anyway, even if the window is minimized to the tray. (I use WinExist before your code to ensure OBS is running).